# JSON Error Value free at 6 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I don't see what's wrong with my JSON, I'm getting the error that it cannot be converted to JSONObject. I searched on the forum but I can't find the answer.

Code (to parse):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.toString().replace("\\", " "));
                    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("timetable");

                    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String class_school = json_data.getString("class");
                        String teacher = json_data.getString("teacher");
                        String subject = json_data.getString("subject");
                        String room = json_data.getString("room");
                        timetList.add(new TimeTable(subject, class_school + " " + teacher + " " + " " + room));
                    }
```

JSON:

```
{"timetable":[{"teacher":"Woh","subject":"BVH","room":"017","change":"no"},{"teacher":"Rrl","subject":"BI","room":"045","change":"no"},{"teacher":"Ajg","subject":"WI","room":"019","change":"no"},{"teacher":"Sgh","subject":"NE","room":"119","change":"no"},{"teacher":"Rom","subject":"FA","room":"116","change":"no"},{"teacher":"Her","subject":"GS","room":"127","change":"no"},"free","free"]}
```

Logcat:

```
03-29 15:06:11.356: E/error(822): Value free at 6 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Looks like you are looping over your `timetable` assuming _all_ the entries would be objects describing a class room occupancy – but the _last two_ entries are no such objects, but mere text literals obviously meant to signify that a room is `"free"` at those times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `String`. Your `JSON` String is broken and it is reason of

> Value free at 6 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   JSONObject

Look at your String:

```
{
  "timetable": [
                {"teacher":"Woh","subject":"BVH","room":"017","change":"no"},
                {"teacher":"Rrl","subject":"BI","room":"045","change":"no"},
                {"teacher":"Ajg","subject":"WI","room":"019","change":"no"},
                {"teacher":"Sgh","subject":"NE","room":"119","change":"no"},
                {"teacher":"Rom","subject":"FA","room":"116","change":"no"},
                {"teacher":"Her","subject":"GS","room":"127","change":"no"},

                "free","free"
              ]
}
```

You need to remove this unexpected sequence:

```
"free","free"
```

and last comma in `JSONObject` with teacher's value `Her` and it should work.

Comment: Per json.org, it looks like heterogeneous arrays are fine; a `value` can be a string, number, object, array, boolean, or `null`.  So why can't there be two strings in an array that otherwise contains objects?

Comment: @Richard this sequence is not correct, it has no value,nokey, JSON working as key-value pairs..and this sequence is plain text.

Comment: You haven't said why the two strings "free" can't be inside an array.

Comment: @Richard now i said it, `JSONArray` may contains either next array or object or both but this sequence is neither array nor object but it's plain text.

Comment: A string is a valid value inside of a `JSONArray`; see http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString(int)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, you're trying to parse last two entries ("free","free") to a JSONObject. If for some reason you need to add empty entries use {}.

Consider using optString instead of getString (or use try catch statment to handle exception)

Answer (score 0):

Your string is valid JSON; however

```
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

assumes that the entity at array position `i` be a JSON object.  "free" is a string, which is not an object type in JSON (not surrounded by {}), `getJSONObject(i)` throws this exception when you try to make an object out of a string.

The strings can be extracted with `jArray.getString(i)`, but the real trick is determining the type of the entity at position `i`.  You can try a generic `jArray.get(i)` and then introspect the returned value to determine its type.